# How to update model object in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using below code for update the status.

```
current_challenge = UserChallengeSummary.objects.filter(user_challenge_id=user_challenge_id).latest('id')
current_challenge.update(status=str(request.data['status']))
```

I am getting below error:

> 'UserChallengeSummary' object has no attribute 'update'

For solve this error:
I found solutions:

```
current_challenge.status = str(request.data['status'])
current_challenge.save()
```

Is there any another way to update record?

Comment: as far as I know, your solution is ordinary for django

Answer (score 6):

Your working solution is the way usually used in Django, as @Compadre already said.

But sometimes (for example, in tests) it's useful to be able to update multiple fields at once. For such cases I've written simple helper:

```
def update_attrs(instance, **kwargs):
    """ Updates model instance attributes and saves the instance
    :param instance: any Model instance
    :param kwargs: dict with attributes
    :return: updated instance, reloaded from database
    """
    instance_pk = instance.pk
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if hasattr(instance, key):
            setattr(instance, key, value)
        else:
            raise KeyError("Failed to update non existing attribute {}.{}".format(
                instance.__class__.__name__, key
            ))
    instance.save(force_update=True)
    return instance.__class__.objects.get(pk=instance_pk)
```

Usage example:

```
current_challenge = update_attrs(current_challenge, 
                                 status=str(request.data['status']),
                                 other_field=other_value)
                                 # ... etc.
```

If you with, you can remove `instance.save()` from the function (to call it explicit after the function call).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I definitely use your solution for solve my problem.

Comment: I'd rather recommend you to look at the 'raw' Django way to update models once again — it's pretty OK to use. I use the code provided above only to keep my unittests shorter.

Comment: Yes, We can use raw query. But it would be easy if we can achieve using ORM query.

Comment: @Soham Navadiya: by 'raw' Django way I mean ORM calls you provided in your post, not raw SQL!

Comment: Thanks! This solves my issue of having to update an object with a different amount of variables. I think such method should be added to Django repo itself.

Answer (score 0):

[latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#latest) method returns the latest object which is an instance of `UserChallengeSummary`, which doesn't have an update method.

For updating single objects, your method is standard.

[update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) method is used for updating multiple objects at once, so it works on `QuerySet` instances.