# django ModelForms - am I doing it right?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a polls app extension that uses a 6-field or 8-field answer. I've defined these ModelForms very minimally.

```
class expert_judgement_three_form(ModelForm):
"""From Burgman "Trusting Judgements" 2016 p95. Values are probabilities """
class Meta:
    model = EJ_three_field
    exclude = ['question','user']
```

[The forms seem to need a lot of manual config in the template to get them into estimate : rationale pairs]

To prepopulate the fields, I'm creating an object instance of the model, then passing that to the form, then getting it back from the form. The example in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#field-data) steps through the cleaned_data dictionary item by item - it doesn't seem to reduce boilerplate all that much.  I note [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894573/how-to-update-model-object-in-django) and I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503925/how-do-i-use-a-dictionary-to-update-fields-in-django-models) and am probably going to work this way.

I can't escape the feeling that I've misunderstood or misread the key features of how forms, and in particular modelforms, should be used, because so much is still visible (and giving me trouble).

A good answer to this question would be the sparsest possible model, ModelForm, and View for a multi-field form that always prefills from the users previous answers to questions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a `Form` and `ModelForm` are different.Form are manually configured by you and `ModelForm` will be automatically created.

If you have created a model, you will often want to allow a user to create these models through a form. Instead of having to duplicate all the field names and create the form yourself, Django provides a shortcut for this, the ModelForm:

Example of a model form created with **Modelform**:

**forms.py**

```
class expert_judgement_three_form(ModelForm):
"""From Burgman "Trusting Judgements" 2016 p95. Values are probabilities """
     class Meta:
           model = EJ_three_field
           exclude = ['question','user']
```

This form automatically has all the same field types as the `EJ_three_field` model it was created from.

**views.py**

```
def create(request):
    form = expert_judgement_three_form(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = expert_judgement_three_form(request.POST)
        print form.errors
        if form.is_valid :
            print "all validation passed"
            # commit=False tells Django that "Don't send this to database yet.
            expert_judgement_three_form = form.save(commit=False)
            expert_judgement_three_form.save()
            return (request, "")
        else:
             print form.errors
    else:
        form = expert_judgement_three_form(request.POST)
    return render(request, "",{"form":form})

def edit(request,pk):
    EJ_three_field_object = EJ_three_field.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = expert_judgement_three_form(request.POST,instance=EJ_three_field_object)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = expert_judgement_three_form(request.POST,instance=EJ_three_field_object)
        print form.errors
        if form.is_valid :
            print "all validation passed"
            # commit=False tells Django that "Don't send this to database yet.
            expert_judgement_three_form = form.save(commit=False)
            expert_judgement_three_form.save()
            return (request, "")
        else:
             print form.errors
    else:
        form = expert_judgement_three_form(request.POST,instance=EJ_three_field_object)enter code here
    return render(request, "",{"form":form})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^create/', views.create, name='create'),
#edit
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.edit,name='edit'),
```

Documentation: [Creating forms from ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#topics-forms-modelforms)

Comment: Thanks Emil.  Can you explain why this two-state process is recommended?
 `code`             expert_judgement_three_form = form.save(commit=False)
            expert_judgement_three_form.save()  `code`

Comment: You can give any variable instead of `expert_judgement_three_form`.it is just  a variable .`commit=False` tells Django that "Don't send this to database yet.I have more things I want to do with it." if you want you can set the user object here.

Answer (score 0):

I would explain it in this way.

## 1

Without using `{{form}}` template tag, you should write all yourself `<form action="." method="post">{% csrf token %} <label ...> <input type ...> .. </form>`. So with using form, you can reduce your time for writing all those.

## 2

without modelForm, you need to specify each your input.

```
class Example(forms.Form):
    example1 = forms.CharField(label="label name", max_length=100)
    example2 = forms.IntergerField()
    ... what if you have 10 inputs?, you should write all 10 inputs
```

but if you already define your Model(In many cases, you would make form to save or update in your database. It means you already define your Models.), you can simply use ModelForm without spending time to write FormField yourself.

```
class Example(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        Model : yourModel
        fields : ['example1', 'example2', ...]
```

I could be secure, i thinks. If you define your model element like

```
#model.py
class ExampleModelCalss(models.Model):
    example1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

#forms.py
class ExampleFormClass(forms.Form):
    example1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

you can type text which has length 70, so it pass form validation but what happen when it save in your database?

so my idea is like that. I am curious how other people think.

In addition, you can mix it.
For example,

```
#models.py
class ExampleModelCalss(models.Model):
    example1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    example2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

you want to add one which is not in your Model.

```
class ExampleMixForm(forms.ModelForm)
    example3 = forms.CharField(max_length=50) # adding
    
    class Meta:
        Model : ExampleModelCalss
        fields = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'] # adding
```

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now! I thought I would put up this working code in case someone finds it useful.  One of the sources of difficulty, which might make this interesting, is that I am using forms only for multi-field answers, and not using them for single field answers. Any review comments on this would be quite welcome. I am very new to this.

## models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
...
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# What follows is a class method that gets existing answers, creates new default entries or updates answers depending on when it is called. It assumes that each question is answered only once.
    @classmethod
    def get_or_update_answer(self, user, question, submitted_value={None}):
        if question.answer_type == 'CH':
            if submitted_value == {None}:
                selected_choice = question.choice_set.first() # by default, select the top of a set of radio buttons
                answer, _created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(user = user, question = question, defaults={'choice':selected_choice})

            else:
                selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=submitted_value)
                answer = Vote.objects.get(user = user, question = question)
                answer.choice = selected_choice

        if question.answer_type == 'SA':
            if submitted_value == {None}:
                submitted_value = "brief response"
                answer, _created = Short_Answer.objects.get_or_create(user = user, question = question, defaults={'short_answer': submitted_value})

            else:
                answer = Short_Answer.objects.get(user = user, question = question)
                answer.short_answer = submitted_value

        if question.answer_type == 'LA':
            if submitted_value == {None}:
                submitted_value = "full response"
                answer, _created = Long_Answer.objects.get_or_create(user = user, question = question, defaults={'long_answer':submitted_value})

            else:
                answer = Long_Answer.objects.get(user = user, question = question)
                answer.long_answer = submitted_value
        if question.answer_type == 'E3':
            if submitted_value == {None}:
                submitted_value = {'lowest_value': 0, 'lv_rationale': "low estimate reasons",
                                  'highest_value':0,  'hv_rationale': "high estimate reasons",
                                  'best_value':0, 'bv_rationale': "best estimate reasons",}
                answer, _created = EJ_three_field.objects.get_or_create(user= user, question = question, defaults=submitted_value)
            else:
                answer = EJ_three_field.objects.get(user= user, question = question)
                for key, value in submitted_value.items():
                    setattr(answer,key,value)
        if question.answer_type == 'E4':
            if submitted_value == {None}:
                submitted_value = {'lowest_value': 0, 'lv_rationale': "low estimate reasons",
                                  'highest_value':0,  'hv_rationale': "high estimate reasons",
                                  'best_value':0, 'bv_rationale': "best estimate reasons",
                                  'confidence': 0, 'conf_rationale': "reasons for confidence score",}
                answer, _created = EJ_four_field.objects.get_or_create(user = user, question = question, defaults=submitted_value)
            else:
                answer = EJ_four_field.objects.get(user= user, question = question)
                for key, value in submitted_value.items():
                    setattr(answer,key,value)
        # answer.save() - not required for create / update funcs
        answer.save()
        return answer

class Short_Answer(Answer):
class Long_Answer(Answer):
class Vote(Answer):
class EJ_three_field(Answer):
class EJ_four_field(Answer):
```

## Views.py

```
def pageView(request, user_id, page_num):
    question_set = Question.objects.filter(man_page = page_num)
    user = User.objects.get(username = user_id)
    template = 'polls/page_question.html'
    context = {'question_set' : question_set, }
    forms = {}
    answers = {}
    for question in question_set:
        answers[question] = Answer.get_or_update_answer(user, question)
        form_instance = form_instantiator(question, instance = answers[question])
        forms[question] = form_instance

    context['forms']=forms
    context['answers']=answers
    return render(request, template, context)

@login_required
def answer(request, user_id, man_index):
    #attempt to standardise saving of answers (votes, shorts, longs, E3, vE4 etc)
    user = User.objects.get(username = user_id)
    question = Question.objects.get(man_index = man_index)
    form_instance = form_instantiator(question, request = request)
    if form_instance == None:
        answer_value = request.POST['answer_value']
        Answer.get_or_update_answer(user = user, question = question, submitted_value = answer_value)
    else:
        form = form_instantiator(question, request = request)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            Answer.get_or_update_answer(user = user, question = question, submitted_value = form.cleaned_data)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:page', args=(user_id, question.man_page)))
```

To answer my original question: a ModelForm can be created with an (instance=) or a (request.POST) or unbound, with neither.  The object passed with context is discarded when the data is submitted.  A ModelForm can be saved with form.save(), which is very efficient.